# VBA - Missing Operator SQL Query Error

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to update the table with inner join using VBA in MS Access but 
I've tested the SQL `Update` statement in SQL Server Management Studio and it's working. I'm getting an error as a result, see below.

Appreciate any help.

```
SQL = "Update A set A.RevBillCtrl = 8 from dbo_tblMain A inner join dbo_tblPlateNo as B ON B.PNC = A.PLC inner join dbo_tblSubcons as C on B.SCC = C.SCC "
```

[image]

Comment: What data type is `A.RevBillCtrl`?

Comment: Data type of A.RevBillCtrl is integer.

Answer (score 1):

In Access the Update with joins has a different syntax comparing to SQL Server. The correct syntax will be:

```
Update dbo_tblMain AS A 
inner join dbo_tblPlateNo as B on B.PNC = A.PLC 
inner join dbo_tblSubcons as C on B.SCC = C.SCC
set A.RevBillCtrl = 8
```

BTW, earlier Access versions did not like the INNER JOINS that follow one after another. They used a nested joins syntax:

```
Update dbo_tblMain AS A 
inner join (dbo_tblPlateNo as B
  inner join (dbo_tblSubcons as C 
  on B.SCC = C.SCC)
on B.PNC = A.PLC)
set A.RevBillCtrl = 8
```

Comment: I have tried below query but i'm getting an error.

RunTime Error '3075' : 
Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'B.PNC = A.PLC inner join dbo_tblSubcons AS C ON B.SCC = C.SC'.

    Update dbo_tblMain A 
    inner join dbo_tblPlateNo as B ON B.PNC = A.PLC 
    inner join dbo_tblSubcons as C on B.SCC = C.SCC
    set A.RevBillCtrl = 8

Comment: try one with the nested joins

Comment: sorry, messed the nested joins syntax. try again

Comment: The bottom block was the same as the top one, so I edited the bottom one to a nested join, but *then* realized there were parentheses.. and I don't know whether parentheses are mandatory in Access, nor where they're supposed to be going - so I edited it further, but I think I should have just left it alone... feel free to rollback or fix or whatever.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: yes, Access's craziness around their joins makes everyone crazy

Comment: By the way, my application's back end is MSSQL2008R2.

Answer (score 0):

The idea basically is that you have to do the JOINs in a nested way.
See below correct one.

```
Sql = "UPDATE dbo_tblMain
      INNER JOIN (dbo_tblPlateNo 
       INNER JOIN dbo_tblSubCons 
       ON (dbo_tblPlateNo.SCC = dbo_tblSubCons.SCC)) 
      ON (dbo_tblMain.PLC = dbo_tblPlateNo.PNC) 
      SET dbo_tblMain.RevBillCtrl = 8"
```

Comment: Test your queries by writing them as an actual query not in vba. Not sure u need vba here. If you just use query desinger to drag the joins, access will handle the syntax